# ponnamkarthik/toast/fluttertoast/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt when compile flutter

Tags: dart

when I compile my flutter project, it shows:

```
To see a detailed report, use the --untranslated-messages-file 
option in the tool to generate a JSON format file containing 
all messages that need to be translated.
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: /home/dolphin/apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.1.5/android/src/main/kotlin/io/github/ponnamkarthik/toast/fluttertoast/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (16, 16): Redeclaration: MethodCallHandlerImpl
e: /home/dolphin/apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-7.1.6/android/src/main/kotlin/io/github/ponnamkarthik/toast/fluttertoast/MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (17, 16): Redeclaration: MethodCallHandlerImpl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

It works fine right now, then I tried to upgrade the  `fluttertoast`:

```
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
```

but still not work, what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to fluttertoast: 7.1.5
Run Pub get and run your project
After this you can change to fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
Obviusly this is not the best wey to fix this error but it works for me.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try Executing following commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```